# Why won't this while loop break?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

`date[inc] = [0] = "01/01/2011"`

`dateTimePicker1.Value = {01/01/2011 00:00:00}`

The if condition is never fulfilled when changing a secondary datetimepicker. The first datetimepicker has to be changed once before this code will work. This code is triggered by a `ValueChanged` in both cases.

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
int start;
int inc = 0;
while (true)
{
   inc++;
   if (Convert.ToString(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()) == date[inc])
   {
      start = inc;
      inc = 0;
      break;
   }  
}
```

=/=

```
int start;
int inc = 0;
while (true)
{
   if (Convert.ToString(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()) == date[inc])
   {
      start = inc;
      inc = 0;
      break;
   }  
   inc++;
}
```

Still very helpful comments, thanks everyone. Obviously was missing the first date because of an increment, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: From your description ("first datetimepicker has to be changed once before this code will work"), the code you posted is likely unrelated to the actual problem. Check to see what the value of the first datetimepicker is before running this loop. You might find it is something unexpected (like an empty string) in the first case. The ValueChanged event only fires when a selection *changes*, not on the first time.

Comment: I probably should have asked before answering but how are your culture settings set for short date format?

Comment: Both run the same code, as above. The second one gets stuck in an endless loop though. The value of the first picker is as shown, and the date of the second is not used until after this loop has completed.

Ah, how do I check this?

Comment: Wait, why do you have an infinite loop with no definite termination condition in the first place? What happens if `inc` goes beyond the end of the `date` array?

Comment: More imporantly, what is the result of `Convert.ToString(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString())`?

Comment: @GregHewgill - Apparently that is what the OP is trying to avoid with this question. Sounds like a good reason to me. :)

Comment: I'll just increase the date by a day each time until the value is found, the picker is set to dynamic bounds, i.e. it can't go beyond the end of the array ... hopefully :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compare like this

```
if (dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy",
       new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US") == date[inc])
```

OR

```
//Considering your date format is MM/dd/yyyy, coz 01/01/2011 doesn't help in uderstanding
//in date format, if it would have been 01/13/2011, it would have helped
if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date == 
       DateTime.ParseExact(date[inc], "MM/dd/yyyy", 
           new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")).Date)
```

Also you can do `.Trim()` on `date[inc]` it might help you.

**EDIT**

When you compare `string` things to look for

- White Spaces at beginning and at end. Remove them if required using `.Trim()`
- Case Sensitivity. Do `string.Equals(string1, string2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Show off :P you must actually want to *help* these people. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a string comparison:

```
"01/01/2011" != "1/1/2011"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") == date[inc])
// ...
```

Comment: No luck, this is very helpful though!

Answer (score 0):

if the strings are never equal, theres no condition to break out on ever